# Customize a button in jquerymobile?

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

thats my JQueryMobile button:

```
    <p><a href="#test1" data-role="button" class="testbutton1">Test 1</a></p>
```

and thats the css spezification:

```
.testbutton1 {
    /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";   
}
```

When I load the html side. nothing happens?
Whats my mistake?

thx in advance

--*1.Update*--
Thx for your answer!
Ok this is what I am supporting:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

but nothing happens... LOL

Comment: Even without jquery.mobile.css it should work - http://jsfiddle.net/Jhvqh/1/ What browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have included:

- core jQuery
- jQuery mobile
- jQuery mobile CSS

and it should work - http://jsfiddle.net/Jhvqh/

Also I don't think you need to support old IE-s on mobile devices.